# Wix Bootstrapper - DownloadUrl - Can it be a local network path?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I want to have my exePackage saved on a network path and for the bootrapper to "download" it from this place if needed.

I cannot get the bootstapper to work with the path.  My log says failed to connect to ....

I have tried may different things with the / or \ and with "file" at the beginning.  But I cannot seem to get it right.  Firefox, Internet Explorer and file explorer all have no problem with this format, however wix will change it in the log.  The log show "file://servname..."

```
DownloadUrl="file://///servname/foldername1/foldername2/folder%20withaspace/myEXE.exe"
```

What should it be?

EDIT: One work around would be to use the Source attribute and have it pointing to the network path. But my development pc with Visual Studio (M$ version) does not have access to this network share so I cannot use the Name or Source of the exePackage to refer to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn supports downloading from BITS, FTP, HTTP, and HTTPS. It doesn't support SMB shares.

Comment: Thanks, in the Wix 3.6 Developer's Guide by Nick Ramirez he says on downloading packages "...from the internet or a local network" I kinda thought local network meant also file. Any workarounds? If the source file is placed on the network drive then it finds it and "downloads it"

Comment: Burn automatically uses a package if it's uncompressed and in the correct directory relative to the bundle. But if you explicitly tell Burn to download it, it must be available via BITS, FTP, HTTP, or HTTPS. You should keep packages in source control so they're available when building the bundle. It's also good source-control management, so you can version your dependencies.